# Tensorboard train data not same number of steps as validation data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I am setting up tensorboard using keras. Here is the code I'm using:

```
tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir)
model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'sgd', metrics = ['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 40, 
                   validation_data = (X_valid, y_valid), 
                   callbacks = [tensorboard_callback])
```

When I run it, I get unexpected plots:

[image: accuracy curves]

So the curves make it look like there were more runs for the validation data than the training data (orange). However, during training the feedback shows I'm getting results for all 40 epochs. E.g.,: here are the last few lines after `running model.fit()`:

```
Epoch 37/40
55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 122us/sample - loss: 0.2029 - accuracy: 0.9274 - val_loss: 0.2961 - val_accuracy: 0.8954
Epoch 38/40
55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 120us/sample - loss: 0.2010 - accuracy: 0.9288 - val_loss: 0.2974 - val_accuracy: 0.8920
Epoch 39/40
55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 121us/sample - loss: 0.1958 - accuracy: 0.9299 - val_loss: 0.3039 - val_accuracy: 0.8914
Epoch 40/40
55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 120us/sample - loss: 0.1943 - accuracy: 0.9307 - val_loss: 0.2954 - val_accuracy: 0.8960
```

Have run it multiple times, with different numbers of epochs, and always see this disparity in the plots.